# Can the RawInput API be used to read raw input and prevent Windows from processing the input afterwards?

Tags: c#, api, barcode, barcode-scanner, raw-input

I would like to use the RawInput API for a barcode reader, but I do not want the barcode reader's output to be processed by Windows after I am done with it.

The reason I would like to use the RawInput API is that it allows me to discern between regular keyboard input and barcode reader input.

I know that this can be done using a low level keyboard procedure, but that does not provide any information on the device responsible for the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the following question it appears not to be possible to use the RawInput API to swallow key input: [Is it possible to swallow a key in Raw Input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042211/is-it-possible-to-swallow-a-key-in-raw-input).

One other possibility would be to set focus to my application from the RawInput API and handle the input in the main form's KeyPress event. This way I can suppress the keys by settings the e.Handled state to true.

Another alternative would be to use both a global hook and the RawInput API, but this would require two separate processes as the RawInput API unhooks any global hook within the same process.